How to corroct get notification permission in Objc?
I have a way to get push permissions.
But what I get every time is not the correct value.
How can I rewrite this method?
My push permission has been enabled, but it still prints out 555 first and then 111.
But when I call this method outside, I have already obtained False first.
How can I make the whole method normal?
- (BOOL)getNotificationPermission
{
    __block BOOL hasPermission;

    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings *settings){

        switch (settings.authorizationStatus) {
            case UNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
                hasPermission = YES;
                NSLog(@"111");
                break;
            case UNAuthorizationStatusDenied:
                hasPermission = NO;
                NSLog(@"222");
                break;
            case UNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
                hasPermission = NO;
                NSLog(@"333");
                break;
            default:
                hasPermission = NO;
                NSLog(@"444");
                break;
        }
    }];

    NSLog(@"555");

    return hasPermission;
}

Log
555
111


That is the expected output.  The completion handler executes asynchronously, but the print of 555 is outside of the completion handler, so it executes first.  Some time later the completion handler executes and you get 111.  You need to pass a completion handler to this method which you can invoke to provider the value back to the caller.

If you were in Swift you could potentially use async/await to make your code linear, but it is still going to be an asynchronous operation.
